# Split a number by decimal point in php

Tags: php, split

How do I split a number by the decimal point in php?

I've got $num = 15/4; which turns $num into 3.75. I would like to split out the 3 and the 75 parts, so $int = 3 and $dec = 75. My non-working code is:

```
$num = 15/4; // or $num = 3.75;
list($int, $dec) = split('.', $num);
```

but that results in empty $int and $dec.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you `explode` the decimal representation of the number, you lose precision.  If you don't mind, so be it (that's ok for textual representation).  Take the locale into account!  We Belgians use a comma (at least the non-programming ones :).

If you *do* mind (for computations e.g.), you can use the `floor` function:

```
$num = 15/4
if ($num > 0) {
    $intpart = floor( $num );    // results in 3
    $fraction = $num - $intpart; // results in 0.75
} else {
    $intpart = ceil( $num );     // results in -3
    $fraction = $num - $intpart; // results in -0.75
}
```

Comment: Brazilians also use commas for decimal separators and periods for thousandths separators. Use http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php to figure out what the correct separator is for your locale

Comment: Belgians and Brazilians are not so different :).  Someone should really write a library for this.

Answer (score 7):

```
$num = 15/4; // or $num = 3.75;
list($int, $dec) = explode('.', $num);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try [explode](http://php.net/explode)

```
list($int,$dec)=explode('.', $num);
```

as you don't really need to use a regex based split. [Split](http://php.net/split) wasn't working for you as a '.' character would need escaping to provide a literal match.

Comment: Note that you _do_ lose precision this way - don't base calculations on that.

Answer (score 4):

```
$int = $num > 0 ? floor($num) : ceil($num);
$dec = $num - $int;
```

If you want `$dec` to be positive when `$num` is negative (like the other answers) you could do:

```
$dec = abs($num - $int);
```

Comment: Fails for negative numbers, e.g. if $num=-17.3, then $int=18 and $dec=0.7

Answer (score 2):

```
$num = 3.75;
$fraction = $num - (int) $num;
```

Answer (score 2):

In case when you don't want to lose precision, you can use these:

```
$number = 10.10;
$number = number_format($number, 2, ".", ",");
sscanf($number, '%d.%d', $whole, $fraction);

// you will get $whole = 10, $fraction = 10
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what this is doing, but it worked for me. I was using the explode() method but when the second part of the array is the number "0", I was getting an "illegal offset" error.

Answer (score 2):

This works for positive AND negative numbers:

```
$num = 5.7;
$whole = (int) $num;         //  5
$frac  = $num - (int) $num;  // .7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 15/4;
substr(strrchr($num, "."), 1)
```

Comment: Please explain a little more about your answer.